# How to add a new information page to my Ruby on Rails site

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm very new to Rails so this is probably quite easy for most but I want to add a new page with simply some static information and a link back home. How do I create this and where does the file live?

Any help would be great! Thank you.

Comment: Since you are "very new to Rails", I strongly advise to read [Rails Tutorial](https://www.railstutorial.org/book), where one of the first Rails excercises is exactly adding static pages.

Comment: Ah thanks D-side, I haven't seen this before but it looks very useful so I will read it cover to cover

Answer (score 2):

Just create a controller with an action for your static page. For example

```
rails g controller home about
```

will generate a controller named `HomeController` with an action `about` that has a corresponding view in `views/home/about.html.erb` which you can edit.

Comment: So if I already have an index.html.erb and a new.html.erb inside  app/views/jobs then do I input: rails g controller jobs about ?

Comment: rails g controller jobs about has given me a conflict

Comment: at the moment I have an index which is viewed at website.com/ and a /new page which is viewed at website.com/new so I would like the about page to be website.com/about and not website.com/home/about - how would I do this?

Comment: @user2498890 You ask a lot of questions that can be found in the [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html). Please read it and come back when you have more questions. Happy to help you then.

Answer (score 1):

In your routes:

```
get 'my_static_info_page' to: 'application#my_static_info_page'
```

In your controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ApplicationController::Base

  def my_static_info_page
  end

end
```

Then create a view under 'app/views/my_static_info_page.html.erb'

Essentially just create a route as you would for any new action you want to define on a controller.  It can be on any controller, all that changes is where you route it to, where you define the controller action and where you put the view.